# Long node undesiringly cropped outside of pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots, nodes

I have a node within a `pgfplot` that is rather long. I know I can move the node along using `pos` but that's not what I want, since in the actual applications I have more objects on the plot. On the other hand I have space outside of the plot, yet the plot seems to automatically crop. The MWE below displays the problem to be solved.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[
        font=\scriptsize,
        axis lines=left,
        ]

\addplot[domain=0:30]
{10+1*x}node[sloped,pos=0.7,below]{Please show all of me even though I am long};

\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}%  

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use the key `clip=false` in the `axis` options... see page 325 of the 1.12 manual

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm sure this must have been asked already, but I cannot find a previous question, so I'll give an answer...

You need to add `clip=false` to the `axis` options, as shown on page 325 of the v1.12 [`pgfplots` manual](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        font=\scriptsize,
        axis lines=left,
        clip=false,
        ]

\addplot[domain=0:30]
{10+1*x}node[sloped,pos=0.7,below]{Please show all of me even though I am long};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

[image]